# How to pass a list in an arg function for being readable in SQL?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, psycopg2

I using SQL module in psycopg2 and I'm trying to pass a list as arg a function.

```
def getSomething(*args):

 query = sql.SQL("select col1 from tb1 where col1 in ({})").format(
        sql.SQL(', ').join([sql.Literal(ar) for ar in args])
    )
 print query.as_string(Connection())
```

Tried in different ways but without success. One of them was, I received a unicode type via POST.

```
data = request.form['data']
d_array = data.split(',')
print getsomething(d_array)
```

output d_array `[u'66626', u'66635']`

```
InvalidTextRepresentation('invalid input syntax for integer: "66626,66635"\nLINE 9:     WHERE col1 in (\'66626,66635\')\n                               ^\n',)
```

If I pass these values separated `getSomething('66626','66635')` works!

My question is about unpack this list in separate values and them put in function as arg or is there another thing to do it?

Comment: Test without the * in the parameter name.

Comment: It worked.  Thanks! Please write the answer, that way I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "*" is an unpacking operator in Python.

You don't need unpacking a parameter, if this parameter is a list.

Just remove the "*" before the parameter's name.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the `*` in python is an *unpacking* operator, i.e. it unpacks a sequence, if set as a function parameter it effectively allows you to pass an unpacked sequence (i.e. numerous variables and they will all be made available in the function body as the name defined.), however when passed to a function as an argument it unpacks the sequence and passes it to the function as each item individually.

```
In [1]: def starred(*args): 
   ...:     print(type(args)) 
   ...:     print(args) 
   ...:                                                                         

In [2]: def pass_starred(arg1, arg2, arg3): 
   ...:     print(arg1, arg2, arg3) 
   ...:                                                                         

In [3]: data = [1, 2, 3]                                                        

In [4]: starred(data)                                                           
<class 'tuple'>
([1, 2, 3],)

In [5]: pass_starred(*data)                                                     
1 2 3
```

(btw, if you look at the `print` function, this is how it can print any number of arguments, effectively it gets all non-named arguments as a starred variable and it iterates and prints them.)